# Do systemcalls context switch to some kernel-space thread/process, or elevate the privilages of the calling thread/process?

Tags: linux, system-calls

This is probably a newbie question, please correct me if I understood something wrongly

When talking about syscalls, I always hear "we enter kernel-space temporarily and then go back to user-space"
But what does that mean?
Does the process (or thread? I'm not sure) get full kernel-space privileges, or does a context switch occur and a certain kernel-space thread executes the syscall?

If prior is the correct one, then isn't it a big security vulnerability?

Comment: Security vulnerability? No. Privileges are linked to the code, so you get kernel privileges only when you execute kernel code. And kernel code should always validate user space data. And you cannot execute your code with kernel privileges.. So it should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

On most architectures, threads and processes are software concepts, created by OS. The hardware doesn't know and doesn't care about threads and processes.

On all architectures that support privilege modes, any change from User to Kernel also performs a jump to a new address. Moreover, this address is always stored in a kernel-only register or a kernel-only memory — so the user-mode code has no control over the jump destination. Of course, the kernel code can transfer control to any other code, but a correctly designed OS would never do that. It should always switch to user mode before jumping to user-mode code.

It is important to remember, that the CPU does not execute "threads" — it executes some specific instructions from some specific address. It does not matter, that the "thread" technically belongs to a user program: if the Program Counter points to a trusted code, and the execution started from some pre-approved starting point — the result of that code can also be trusted.

Answer (score -1):

It is a context switch when you jump into a system call.

Comment: Isn't it when you switch any currently running process?

Comment: if you call a function in the same process, it's not a context switch.